# How do I convert this code from VBA to AppleScript?

Tags: vba, ms-word, applescript

I am trying to convert this code from VBA to AppleScript 2.5.

```
Sub testMacro()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim InDoc As Document, OutDoc As Document, i As Long
    Dim RngOut As Range, RngNm As Range, StrNm As String
    Set InDoc = ActiveDocument
    With InDoc
        Set RngOut = ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0)
        Dim obj As New DataObject
        For i = 1 To 3
            Set RngOut = RngOut.GoTo(What:=wdGoToPage, Name:=i)
            Set RngOut = RngOut.GoTo(What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\page")
            RngOut.Copy
            Set OutDoc = Documents.Add
            With OutDoc
                .Range.Paste
                .Characters.Last.Delete
                Set RngNm = .Paragraphs.First.Range
                RngNm.End = RngNm.End - 1
                StrNm = RngNm.Text
                .Paragraphs.First.Range.Delete
                obj.SetText StrNm
                obj.PutInClipboard
                .Close
            End With
        Next i
    End With
    Set RngOut = Nothing: Set RngNm = Nothing
    Set InDoc = Nothing: Set OutDoc = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I was told I could just do the following, but it doesn't work:

```
tell application "Microsoft Word"
    activate
    do Visual Basic "GetPage
        End Sub

        Sub GetPage()
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            Dim InDoc As Document, OutDoc As Document, i As Long
            Dim RngOut As Range, RngNm As Range, StrNm As String
            Set InDoc = ActiveDocument
            With InDoc
                Set RngOut = ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0)
                Dim obj As New DataObject
                For i = 1 To 3
                    Set RngOut = RngOut.GoTo(What:=wdGoToPage, Name:=i)
                    Set RngOut = RngOut.GoTo(What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:=\"\page\")
                    RngOut.Copy
                    Set OutDoc = Documents.Add
                    With OutDoc
                        .Range.Paste
                        .Characters.Last.Delete
                        Set RngNm = .Paragraphs.First.Range
                        RngNm.End = RngNm.End - 1
                        StrNm = RngNm.Text
                        .Paragraphs.First.Range.Delete
                        obj.SetText StrNm
                        obj.PutInClipboard
                        .Close
                    End With
                Next i
            End With
            Set RngOut = Nothing: Set RngNm = Nothing
            Set InDoc = Nothing: Set OutDoc = Nothing
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True"
end tell
```

I keep getting this error: **Expected end of line, etc. but found identifier.** and it highlights the following (Which I bolded): *do **Visual** Basic "GetPage*

Essentially, this code is supposed to get the first word of each page of a document and insert the first word, on the last page it loops to, into the clipboard.

Comment: FYI: `do Visual Basic` is a command from office 2001 and earlier.  it's been replaced (as Patrick Wynne pointed out) by `run VB macro`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`do Visual Basic` is not an AppleScript command in Microsoft Word's AppleScript dictionary, so that will not work.

(Not only that, but your VBA code in your example is invalid anyway.)

`run VB macro` *is* an AppleScript command for Word, so if you have a VBA macro called `GetPage`, say in your `Normal.dot` project, you can use this AppleScript code to run it:

```applescript
tell application "Microsoft Word"
    run VB macro macro name "GetPage"
end tell
```

(NOTE: I'm assuming your VBA code will work in the Mac version of Word. I haven't tried it and fixing it if it doesn't would be a different matter.)

Here's a quick AppleScript I whipped up that should do what you want. It grabs the first word of every page and copies them to the clipboard. Be aware that this has had the bare minimum of testing, but it did work against a 79-page Word document I had lying around.

```applescript
use AppleScript version "2.5"
use scripting additions
use framework "Foundation"

to trimText:inText

    set _str to current application's NSString's stringWithString:inText
    set _whitespace to current application's NSCharacterSet's whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet()
    set _str to _str's stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:_whitespace
    return _str as text

end trimText:

on run

    set wordList to {}
    set lastPage to false

    tell application "Microsoft Word"

        tell active document
            set firstWord to word 1

            repeat until lastPage
                set pageWord to my trimText:(content of firstWord)
                if pageWord ≠ "" then set end of wordList to pageWord
                set nextPage to go to next firstWord what goto a page item
                if (start of content of nextPage) is not equal to (start of content of firstWord) then
                    set firstWord to word 1 of nextPage
                else
                    set lastPage to true
                end if
            end repeat
        end tell

    end tell

    if (count of wordList) is greater than 0 then
        set {oldDelims, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to {AppleScript's text item delimiters, linefeed}
        set the clipboard to (wordList as text)
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to oldDelims
    end if

end run
```

Comment: Good point. I was pasting the results into BBEdit and it converted the line endings to linefeed so I wasn't even noticing that.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I just tested the code with my 172 page document and it worked perfectly from what I can tell.